# C#, can you add generic property to all data entry controls without inheriting? (Similar to an extension method)

Tags: c#, generics, properties

perhaps there are alternative strategies, but I have a settings application which allows the setting of many values.  I was thinking it might be handy if each type of control (textbox, checkbox, combobox, datagridivew) had an IsDirty flag which is set whenever the value is edited by the user.

Naturally, I could wrap each in a user control, but I was wondering if there was a way of doing this similar to an extension method or such which would avoid having to create user controls for each of these.

any thoughts?

thanks
Matt

Answer (score 4):

Check out .NET's [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx), which is designed to be used for "adding" properties to objects. This could be used effectively with extension methods:

```
public static class DirtyExtensions {
    private class ExtraPropertyHolder {
        public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    }

    private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<Control, ExtraPropertyHolder> _isDirtyTable 
        = new ConditionalWeakTable<Control, ExtraPropertyHolder>();    

    public static bool IsDirty(this Control @this) {
        return _isDirtyTable.GetOrCreateValue(@this).IsDirty;
    }

    public static void SetIsDirty(this Control @this, bool isDirty) {
        _isDirtyTable.GetOrCreateValue(@this).IsDirty = value;
    }
}
```

The big benefit of using ConditionalWeakTable is that it avoids you having to wrap every .NET class with a UserControl while handling thread-safety and garbage collection correctly (via weak references).

Comment: Never saw ConditionalWeakTable before; even if it isn't the answer, it's great TIL material.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're on WinForm land, so a custom [extender provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ([sample implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6b055wc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) may work well in these scenarios. Basically you add properties (and handle behaviors when the property is set) on a objects derived from Control object - that is all controls.

Comment: +1 good info. I've changed link to point to interface definition.